# mocking in unit tests with dependency injection

Tags: c#, azure, nunit, ninject, moq

I am wondering about the best way to make my system testable.

I am unsure of the best practice with DI and mocking.

If DI is facilitated by using interfaces should i build mock classes which implement the same interface as the real classes?

And then use these mock classes in my tests via DI?

I importing data into HDInsight. The data is taken from azure queues.

I want to mock/emulate both the queue and the hdinsight so my unit tests are fast and decoupled.

Should i use dependency injection in my tests or is moq sufficient,  are these supposed to operate independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mocks` and `Dependency Injection` go hand in hand because without dependency injection, you would not be able to have your classes use the mocks instead of the real thing. What you don't need is a `Dependency Injection Container` (like Ninject for example). You can use it if you like, but if you did it right, you should be able to Unit-Test your classes by supplying all dependencies yourself.

Comment: OK but if i create a mock queue class with dequeue and enqueue methods etc  and then use this class explicitly in my tests what does moq add to the mix? Feels like i am missing something here.

Comment: Moq can help you write your mocks faster. But if they are complicated and need to be written by hand anyway, you can leave out Moq.

Answer (score 2):

Moq is sufficient.

Your tests use the mocks to help facilitate results. They are quick and easy to setup (once you are used to whatever mocking library you choose).

If you were to utilize a DI framework.. you would be tripling your workload. Not only are you manually stubbing out mocks.. but you are also then maintaining your DI configuration for your tests. This simply wouldn't fit nicely into any workflow.